# Failed to resolve Module specifier. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, import, module, export

I want to import a function form one javascript-file to another. But when I'm running the html-file it says in the browser-console that it can't find the Module I am referring to while ,I think, I did everything right.

In the first javascript file that contains the function I wrote;

```
`export function theFunction() {(here is the function)}'
```

Then in the second javascript file I wrote;

```
`import { theFunction } from "./FirstJavascript.js"'
```

And in the secondhtml.html file I wrote;

```
`<script src="SecondJavascript.js" type=module></script>`
```

All these files are in the same folder. I know that, for modules to work, you must start a local server. So, I did that with node.js and the server contained the folder with all the files. Now, when I open the .html file I get the following error in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "FirstJavascript.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I tried all the things ChatGPT told me to do, but I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error, when using the import statement. I realised that I hadn't installed the relevant modules on the machine I was working on, so they got omitted by the bundler. As a result, the browser can't resolve the module in the bundle and this error gets thrown.